# Jquery animating width accordion style banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built this simple accordion style banner. Here's what it's supposed to do:

- Grab `<li>` containing images from selected `<ul>`.
- Divide them equally within the container (`div.banner`)
- On 'mouseenter', add class `.active` to the hovered `<li>`

  - Shrink the other `<li>`s widths (half their original width).
  - Enlarge active `<li>` to new width (remainder after halving the others)
- On 'mouseleave', all return to original widths.

Works fine until you swipe over multiple panes quickly. If you do, the last of the floated `<li>`'s break to the next line. It appears the total width of the panes is exceeding their container.

Rounding error while animating? Does it have something to do with animate's default 'swing' easing?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UNFc4/

```
var banner = $('.banner');
var list_items = banner.find('li');
var banner_width = $(banner).width();
var num_of_images = $(banner).find('li').length;
var original_width = banner_width / num_of_images;
var half_width = (banner_width / num_of_images) / 2;

var init = function () {
    $(list_items).css('width', original_width);

    $(list_items).on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        doAnimation();

    });
    $(list_items).on('mouseleave', function () {
        resetAnimation();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
}
var doAnimation = function () {
    $(list_items).not(".active").stop().animate({
        width: half_width + "px"
    }, 500);

    $(".active").stop().animate({
        width: (original_width + (half_width * (num_of_images - 1))) + "px"
    }, 500);
}
var resetAnimation = function () {
    $(list_items).stop().animate({
        width: original_width + "px"
    }, 500);
}
init();
```

I could fix it by changing this line, slowing the animation of the others, giving things time to equal out. But, I'd rather solve what's going on here, hopefully learning a bit more about how jQuery's animate() works.

```
 $(list_items).not(".active").stop().animate({
        width: half_width + "px"
    }, 480); // changed 500 to 480
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested, I realized I only needed the reset on the banner area. Now it works, as described, without all the jitteriness and the subsequent layout mis-alignments.

New Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UNFc4/1/

```
$(list_items).on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        doAnimation();
    });
    $(list_items).on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        doAnimation();
    });
    $(banner).on('mouseleave', function () {
        resetAnimation(); 
    });
```